# Issue with Embedded Coder Target for Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I am using the embedded coder target for arduino following this: (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30277-embedded-coder-target-for-arduino). I am having problem while running the myarduino_blink.slx demo.

My MATLAB version is R2015a, and I am using an Arduino Uno. I ran the file setup_custom_target_arduino.m after changing the relevant directory listing and the arduino version in the m file, and I got the output of Arduino on COM 3, which was correct.

After this, I checked the Simulink Library Browser and I had the Custom C/C++ Target Arduino Library will all its modules. Now when I simulate the model, I get the following error:

**Error in S-function 'myarduino_blink/Digital Output':
S-Function 'sfunar_digitalOutput' does not exist**

Kindly help me out, what could I have done wrong?

Comment: ... I think you forgot the error...